# C# define subclass in switch statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create new instance of subclass based on input. For that I'm using switch statement.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    var user = new User();

    switch (model.UserType)
    {
        case UserType.Normal:
            user = (NormalUser) user;
            // NormalUser properties cannot be defined here
            break;
        case UserType.Vip:
            user = (VipUser) user;
            // VipUser properties cannot be defined here
            break;
    }
}
```

Looking for the best solution to solve that.

Comment: Looks like you've found it! :) Move the swith statement to anothere method that returns the model.

Comment: @Wheels73: Look again. OP is trying to cast an object of the base class to suddenly become an object of the derived class ,and that doesn't work.

Comment: you should take a look at Factory pattern. here's some examples [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/factory) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/737117/Factory-Pattern-Example-in-Csharp)

Comment: @Flater - oh yes... still having my breakfast! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `new User()` you´re creating a new instance of this class which has no knowledge of any of its child-classes. Thus casting to any of it fails.

The problem is that the program can´t know how the members that are defined in `NormalUser` but not in the base-class are to be set when executing the cast. So imagine your base-class has members `Name` and Àdress`and your`NormalUser`has an`Age`-property in addition to those two ones. What would you expect would the`Age`be when casting your existing`user`to`NormalUser`. Your program can´t know how to set`Age`.

You´d have to either create a copy-constructor for this to work or don´t instantiate the variable before the switch at all:

```
User user;

switch (model.UserType)
{
    case UserType.Normal:
        user = new NormalUser();
        break;
    case UserType.Vip:
        user = new VipUser()
        break;
}
```

This follows the factory-pattern so users of this method can use it to create instances of a given type without relying on that type which reduces the coupling of your client-code towards the actual types created in the factory.

You also need some `default`-switch to let the compiler know what to do if none of your condition passes - even if this was not possible in your scenario. You might throw an exception in this case for example.

The option with the copy-constructor comes here:

```
class NormalUser
{
    public NormalUser(User user, int age)
    {
        this.Name = user.name;
        this.Adress = user.Adress;
        // further properties defined in the base-class

       this.Age = age
       // further properties defined in NormalUser
    }
}
```

As you see this is much copying of properties. In particular the first option is better for your sneario.

Comment: You'll need a default branch in that switch statement to ensure that user is always assigned (or that an exception has thrown which is my preference for the default branch).

Comment: Although not related to OP's actual problem, it might be better to keep the `var user = new User()` so the compiler stops complaining about a variable that might not be initialised.

Comment: @Flater: Ugh! If you have an invalid/unexpected usertype don't just do something that stops the compiler complaining. If your usertype isn't one of the two you expect you should just throw an exception.

Comment: @Flater The compiler *won´t* complain as all execution-.paths are guaranteed to set the variable. No way to leave it unitialized.

Comment: @Chris: I have come across many companies where flow by exception is not an accepted code standard. While I agree with your reasoning (I've argued the same before), I have to also admit that most places I've worked at would call this an issue of code quality.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: You can't know whether or not the enum has a third option that is not referenced in this particular snippet. Although the _developer_ might know that the third option cannot be used (e.g. because the user was only allowed to pick from two options), the compiler cannot know that based on the code's logic.

Comment: @Flater: In this case it is not flow by exception. You should include all your valid enum types in the switch which means if you get to the default it *is* an exception and should go into your error handling code.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: There may be some confusion that you have mentioned in your writeup the need for a default branch but haven't actually got it in your code.

Comment: @Chris: It's not impossible for the enum to contain a third option which is unused in the _current_ example. E.g. there is a `.NoUser` option but it is omitted here because this code is part of the form that adds a user to an existing account. The developer can prevent the use of the third option (e.g. by forcing the user to pick from only two options), but the compiler still sees that the "NoUser" option _could_ be a valid code path; which means the user variable never gets instantiated.

Comment: @Flater: I quite agree. My point is the default is not where I would handle that. If you know you have another option then put in an explicit branch for it to make it clear its not just a mistake that it has been ommited. And if it is an option that you shouldn't be able to get there I would still have it throw an exception. I might actually make NoUser and default the same branch that throws an exception though more likely I'd throw slightly different exceptions since an unexpected but valid value should throw a different exception to an entirely invalid value.

Comment: @Chris: I see your point. But if you include a default case anyway, it seems redundant to then also add a case for the NoUser option that does the same thing. Is this not a case of DRY?

Comment: The link to the chat seemed to disappear and won't come back when I say move to chat... Here is the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144633/discussion-between-flater-and-chris - I think this is very tangential to the actual question so probably shouldn't be in comments.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't creating new versions of your subtypes, you are just trying to cast the existing object. Try the following.

```
User user;

switch (model.UserType)
{
    case UserType.Normal:
        var newUser =  new NormalUser();
        //set properties...
        user = newUser;
        break;
    case UserType.Vip:
        var newuser =  new VipUser();
        //set properties...
        user = newUser;
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Note you need a default branch or the compiler will complain that user hasn't been properly assigned when you try to use it (since there is theoretically a code path that doesn't set it).

Comment: Although not related to OP's actual problem, it might be better to keep the `var user = new User()` so the compiler stops complaining about a variable that might not be initialised. **edit** or does the default exception already prevent that?

Comment: @Flater: The default exception will prevent that. There is no code path that can leave user unassigned after the switch statement. Either you set the user or you threw an exception (and are thus not in the code following the switch).